# Is tensor argument passing to module expensive?

Tags: matrix, compile, scoping

I wrote a simple module which is supposed to do recursive computation, however it turns out to be expensive even for 300 points. I am not sure why is it slow, all the computations seem to be straightforward algebra. It is also slow when I do `Compile` to `C`. Anyone can spot what exactly hogs it?

```
func[σt_, sρ_, dt_, x_, nnt_] := 
  Module[{kz = 1/2 x, σ = σt, d = dt, i, kp, c, β,
     r, k, ρ = sρ * 10^-6, nn = nnt},
   kp = kz; c = {{1. + 0. I, 0.}, {0., 1.}};

   For[i = 2, i < 2 nn + 2, i++,


    If[EvenQ[i],
     k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[2]] - ρ[[1]])];

      r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[1]]^2); β = 
      I kp d[[1]] ,


     k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[3]] - ρ[[1]])];

      r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[2]]^2); β = 
      I kp d[[2]] 


     ];


    c = c.{{E^β, r E^β}, {r E^-β, E^-β}};

    (*previous k*)
    kp = k
    ];

   Abs[c[[2, 1]]/c[[1, 1]]]^2];
```

Takes around 0.03 seconds with 500 points. Almost same order with `Compile`. Though it compiles cleanly , without going to `MainEvaluate`.

```
AbsoluteTiming@func[{0, 0}, {0, 24, 20}, {6, 4}, 0.6, 300]
```

Here the compiled version:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
f = Compile[{{σt, _Real, 1}, {sρ, _Real, 1}, {dt, _Real, 
    1}, {x, _Real}, {nnt, _Integer}},

  Module[{kz = 1/2 x, σ = σt, d = dt, i, kp, c, β,
      r, k, ρ = sρ * 10^-6, nn = nnt},
    kp = kz; c = {{1. + 0. I, 0.}, {0., 1.}};

    For[i = 2, i < 2 nn + 2, i++,


     If[EvenQ[i],
      k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[2]] - ρ[[1]])];

       r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[1]]^2); β = 
       I kp d[[1]] ,


      k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[3]] - ρ[[1]])];

       r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[2]]^2); β = 
       I kp d[[2]] 


      ];


     c = c.{{E^β, r E^β}, {r E^-β, E^-β}};

     (*previous k*)
     kp = k
     ];

    Abs[c[[2, 1]]/c[[1, 1]]]^2];



  , CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

An extension of the code is to put some conditionals. It renders it completely unimplementable with number of points more than 10, while the one i need is over 300.

```
func[σt_, sρ_, dt_, x_, nnt_] := 
  Module[{kz = 1/2 x, σ = σt, d = dt, i, kp, c, β,
     r, k, ρ = sρ * 10^-6, nn = nnt},
   kp = kz; c = {{1. + 0. I, 0.}, {0., 1.}};

   For[i = 2, i < 2 nn + len - 2 + 1, i++,

    If[2 nn + len - 2 > i - len + 2 >= 0,

     If[EvenQ[i - len + 2],
      k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[-3]] - ρ[[1]])];

      If[i - len + 2 == 0, 
       r = (kp - k)/(kp + k)
          E^(-2 kp k σ[[i - 1]]^2); β = 
        I kp d[[i - 1]] , 
       r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[-1]]^2); β = 
        I kp d[[-1]] ],


      k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[-2]] - ρ[[1]])];

       r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[-2]]^2); β = 
       I kp d[[-2]] 


      ],

     k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[-1]] - ρ[[1]])];

      r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[-1]]^2); β = 
      I kp d[[-1]] 


     ];

    c = c.{{E^β, r E^β}, {r E^-β, E^-β}};

    (*previous k*)
    kp = k
    ];

   Abs[c[[2, 1]]/c[[1, 1]]]^2];
```

UPDATE 1: `Compile` seems to produce great results, with only 0.017sec for 500 points!

```
f = Compile[{{σt, _Real, 1}, {sρ, _Complex, 
    1}, {dt, _Real, 1}, {x, _Real}, {nnt, _Integer}},

  Module[{kz = 1/2 x, σ = σt, d = dt, i, kp, c, β,
     r, k, ρ = sρ * 10^-6, nn = nnt},
   kp = kz + 0. I;
   k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[2]] - ρ[[1]])];
    r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[1]]^2);
   c = {{1 + 0. I, r }, {r , 1}};
   kp = k;

   For[i = 2, i < 2 nn + 2, i++,

    If[EvenQ[i],
     k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[3]] - ρ[[1]])];

      r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[2]]^2); β = 
      I kp d[[1]],


     k = Sqrt[kz^2 - 4 π (ρ[[2]] - ρ[[1]])];

      r = (kp - k)/(kp + k) E^(-2 kp k σ[[3]]^2); β = 
      I kp d[[2]] 


     ];


    c = c.{{E^β, r E^β}, {r E^-β, E^-β}};

    (*previous k*)
    kp = k
    ];

   Abs[c[[2, 1]]/c[[1, 1]]]^2]



  , CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

By the way, how do you make greek letters to appear properly in posts?

Comment: What is `len` in the extended function?

Comment: If I set `len = 3` the exteded function takes the same amount of time as the first definition.

Comment: In that case len will be more than 300, I.e. nn

Comment: Then there is something wrong in the code. If I set `len = 302` and run `AbsoluteTiming@func[{0, 0}, {0, 24, 20}, {6, 4}, 0.6, 300]` I immediately get an error `Part 299 of {0,0} does not exist`. Should your `For` loop perhaps start at `2+len` or something? Should `len` be an argument to the function?

Comment: most of your constants `k,r,etc` simply alternate values between odd/even iterations (Except on the first pass).  This would be far more efficient if you precompute those values outside the loop ( ie. `reven= .. , rodd = ` ).  The fact that they are different only on the first pass make me wonder if your algorithm is really doing what you expect.

Comment: The algorithm works well, just not fast enough to put it into bigger program. I am thinking rewriting it with `Map` and lists to see if it makes things faster as opposed to `For`.

Comment: That's also a good idea, but let's see if we can make it work as-is first. As I said, setting `len =302` and running the code produces errors. Also, george2079's comment should be exploited.

Comment: List thing is even harder to implement, the formulas are in themselves recursive, well fit for procedural programming. I updated my code )